# How to print arrayList from another class using a Vaadin Label?

Tags: java, arraylist, vaadin, mousemove

I have a Canvas.java class where I have a mousemove code to track the mouse position, and have it saved to an array. If I print this  code out from this class itself, the mouse position is correctly printed. However, is there any way I can access this array from another class, and have it printed still (eg. I want it to appear as a Vaadin label in MainLayout.java)? It seems that the label is only showing '[]' in place of the coordinates I want printed.

Canvas.java:

```
package com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.ui.components;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.Component;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.HasSize;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.HasStyle;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.Tag;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Label;
import com.vaadin.flow.dom.Element;
import com.vaadin.flow.dom.ElementFactory;
import elemental.json.JsonObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Canvas component that you can draw shapes and images on. It's a Java wrapper
 * for the
 * <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API">HTML5
 * canvas</a>.
 * <p>
 * Use {@link #getContext()} to get API for rendering shapes and images on the
 * canvas.
 * <p>
 */
@Tag("canvas")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Canvas extends Component implements HasStyle, HasSize {

    private CanvasRenderingContext2D context;
    private Element element;
    private boolean isDrawing = false;
    private boolean mouseIsDown = false;
    private double endX;
    private double endY;

    public static ArrayList <BoundingBox> arrayBoxes = new ArrayList<BoundingBox>();
    public static ArrayList <MousePosition> mousePosArray = new ArrayList<MousePosition>();

    public static ArrayList<BoundingBox> getArrayBoxes() {
        return arrayBoxes;
    }

    public static ArrayList<MousePosition> getMousePosArray() {
        return mousePosArray;
    }

    public static void setMousePosArray(ArrayList<MousePosition> mousePosArray) {
        Canvas.mousePosArray = mousePosArray;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new canvas component with the given size.
     * <p>
     * Use the API provided by {@link #getContext()} to render graphics on the
     * canvas.
     * <p>
     * The width and height parameters will be used for the canvas' coordinate
     * system. They will determine the size of the component in pixels, unless
     * you explicitly set the component's size with {@link #setWidth(String)} or
     * {@link #setHeight(String)}.
     *
     * @param width
     *            the width of the canvas
     * @param height
     *            the height of the canvas
     */
    public Canvas(int width, int height) {

        context = new CanvasRenderingContext2D(this);


        element = getElement();
        element.getStyle().set("border", "1px solid");

        getElement().setAttribute("width", String.valueOf(width));
        getElement().setAttribute("height", String.valueOf(height));

        element.addEventListener("mousedown", event -> {  // Retrieve Starting Position on MouseDown

            Element boundingBoxResult = ElementFactory.createDiv();
            element.appendChild(boundingBoxResult);

            JsonObject evtData = event.getEventData();

            double xBox = evtData.getNumber("event.x");
            double yBox = evtData.getNumber("event.y");
            boundingBoxResult.setAttribute("data-x", String.format("%f", xBox));
            boundingBoxResult.setAttribute("data-y", String.format("%f", yBox));

            BoundingBox newBox = new BoundingBox(0, xBox, yBox, 0.0, 0.0);
            arrayBoxes.add(newBox);

            isDrawing = true;
            mouseIsDown=true;

        }).addEventData("event.x").addEventData("event.y");


        element.addEventListener("mouseup", event -> {  // Draw Box on MouseUp

            Element boundingBoxResult2 = ElementFactory.createDiv();
            element.appendChild(boundingBoxResult2);

            JsonObject evtData2 = event.getEventData();

            endX = evtData2.getNumber("event.x");
            endY = evtData2.getNumber("event.y");
            boundingBoxResult2.setAttribute("end-x", String.format("%f", endX));
            boundingBoxResult2.setAttribute("end-y", String.format("%f", endY));

            double xcoordi = 0;
            double ycoordi = 0;
            double boxWidth = 0;
            double boxHeight = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayBoxes.size(); i++) {
                arrayBoxes.get(i).setName(i + 1);
                arrayBoxes.get(i).setWidth(endX, arrayBoxes.get(i).xcoordi);
                arrayBoxes.get(i).setHeight(endY, arrayBoxes.get(i).ycoordi);
                xcoordi = arrayBoxes.get(i).getXcoordi();
                ycoordi = arrayBoxes.get(i).getYcoordi();
                boxWidth = arrayBoxes.get(i).getWidth();
                boxHeight = arrayBoxes.get(i).getHeight();

            }

                mouseIsDown=false;
                context.beginPath();
                context.setFillStyle("limegreen");
                context.setLineWidth(2);
                context.strokeRect(xcoordi, ycoordi, boxWidth, boxHeight);
                context.fill();

            System.out.println(arrayBoxes.toString());

        }).addEventData("event.x").addEventData("event.y");

        element.addEventListener("mousemove", event -> {  // Retrieve Mouse Position when Moving

                JsonObject mousePos = event.getEventData();

                double mouseX = mousePos.getNumber("event.x");
                double mouseY = mousePos.getNumber("event.y");

                MousePosition currentPos = new MousePosition(mouseX, mouseY);
                mousePosArray.add(0, currentPos);
                setMousePosArray(mousePosArray);
                System.out.println(mousePosArray.get(0));
//                System.out.println(mousePosArray.get(mousePosArray.size() -1));



     }).addEventData("event.x").addEventData("event.y");


    }
```

MainLayout.java:

```
package com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.backend;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.dependency.HtmlImport;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Div;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.H2;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Label;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.NativeButton;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.ui.components.BoundingBox;
import com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.ui.components.Canvas;
import com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.ui.components.CanvasRenderingContext2D;
import com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.ui.components.MousePosition;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.textfield.TextField;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@HtmlImport("frontend://styles/shared-styles.html")
@Route("")

public class MainLayout extends Div {

    private CanvasRenderingContext2D ctx;
    private Canvas canvas;
    ArrayList<MousePosition> mousePosArray = Canvas.getMousePosArray();
    ArrayList<BoundingBox> bb = Canvas.getArrayBoxes();


    public MainLayout() {
        H2 title = new H2("Annotation UI");
        title.addClassName("main-layout__title");

        canvas = new Canvas(1580, 700);

        ctx = canvas.getContext();

        Label label = new Label("Coordinates: " + mousePosArray);
        canvas.addComponent(label);
        add(label);

       }
    }
```

CanvasRenderingContext2D.java:

```
package com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.ui.components;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * The context for rendering shapes and images on a canvas.
 * <p>
 * This is a Java wrapper for the <a href=
 * "https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D">same
 * client-side API</a>.
 */
public class CanvasRenderingContext2D {

    private Canvas canvas;
    public static ArrayList<BoundingBox> arrayBoxes = new ArrayList<BoundingBox>();

    protected CanvasRenderingContext2D(Canvas canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
    }

    public void setFillStyle(String fillStyle) {
        setProperty("fillStyle", fillStyle);
    }

    public void setStrokeStyle(String strokeStyle) {
        setProperty("fillStyle", strokeStyle);
    }

    public void setLineWidth(double lineWidth) {
        setProperty("lineWidth", lineWidth);
    }

    public void setFont(String font) {
        setProperty("font", font);
    }

    public void arc(double x, double y, double radius, double startAngle,
            double endAngle, boolean antiClockwise) {
        callJsMethod("arc", x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, antiClockwise);
    }

    public void beginPath() {
        callJsMethod("beginPath");
    }

    public void clearRect(double x, double y, double width, double height) {
        callJsMethod("clearRect", x, y, width, height);
        Canvas.arrayBoxes.clear();
    }

    public void closePath() {
        callJsMethod("closePath");
    }

    /**
     * Fetches the image from the given location and draws it on the canvas.
     * <p>
     * <b>NOTE:</b> The drawing will happen asynchronously after the browser has
     * received the image.
     * 
     * @param src
     *            the url of the image to draw
     * @param x
     *            the x-coordinate of the top-left corner of the image
     * @param y
     *            the y-coordinate of the top-left corner of the image
     */
    public void drawImage(String src, double x, double y) {
        runScript(String.format(
                "var zwKqdZ = new Image();" + "zwKqdZ.onload = function () {"
                        + "$0.getContext('2d').drawImage(zwKqdZ, %s, %s);};"
                        + "zwKqdZ.src='%s';",
                x, y, src));
    }

    /**
     * Fetches the image from the given location and draws it on the canvas.
     * <p>
     * <b>NOTE:</b> The drawing will happen asynchronously after the browser has
     * received the image.
     * 
     * @param src
     *            the url of the image to draw
     * @param x
     *            the x-coordinate of the top-left corner of the image
     * @param y
     *            the y-coordinate of the top-left corner of the image
     * @param width
     *            the width for the image
     * @param height
     *            the height for the image
     */
    public void drawImage(String src, double x, double y, double width,
            double height) {
        runScript(String.format("var zwKqdZ = new Image();"
                + "zwKqdZ.onload = function () {"
                + "$0.getContext('2d').drawImage(zwKqdZ, %s, %s, %s, %s);};"
                + "zwKqdZ.src='%s';", x, y, width, height, src));
    }

    public void fill() {
        callJsMethod("fill");
    }

    public void fillRect(double x, double y, double width, double height) {
        callJsMethod("fillRect", x, y, width, height);
    }

    public void fillText(String text, double x, double y) {
        callJsMethod("fillText", text, x, y);
    }

    public void lineTo(double x, double y) {
        callJsMethod("lineTo", x, y);
    }

    public void moveTo(double x, double y) {
        callJsMethod("moveTo", x, y);
    }

    public void rect(double x, double y, double width, double height) {
        callJsMethod("rect", x, y, width, height);
    }

    public void restore() {
        callJsMethod("restore");
    }

    public void rotate(double angle) {
        callJsMethod("rotate", angle);
    }

    public void save() {
        callJsMethod("save");
    }

    public void scale(double x, double y) {
        callJsMethod("scale", x, y);
    }

    public void stroke() {
        callJsMethod("stroke");
    }

    public void strokeRect(double x, double y, double width, double height) {
        callJsMethod("strokeRect", x, y, width, height);
    }

    public void strokeText(String text, double x, double y) {
        callJsMethod("strokeText", text, x, y);
    }

    public void translate(double x, double y) {
        callJsMethod("translate", x, y);
    }

    protected void setProperty(String propertyName, Serializable value) {
        runScript(String.format("$0.getContext('2d').%s='%s'", propertyName,
                value));
    }

    /**
     * Runs the given js so that the execution order works with callJsMethod().
     * Any $0 in the script will refer to the canvas element.
     */
    private void runScript(String script) {
        canvas.getElement().getNode().runWhenAttached(
                // This structure is needed to make the execution order work
                // with Element.callFunction() which is used in callJsMethod()
                ui -> ui.getInternals().getStateTree().beforeClientResponse(
                        canvas.getElement().getNode(),
                        context -> ui.getPage().executeJavaScript(script,
                                canvas.getElement())));
    }

    protected void callJsMethod(String methodName, Serializable... parameters) {
        canvas.getElement().callFunction("getContext('2d')." + methodName,
                parameters);
    }

}
```

BoundingBox.java:

```
package com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.ui.components;

public class BoundingBox {

    public double xcoordi = 0;
    public double ycoordi = 0;
    public double boxWidth = 0;
    public double boxHeight = 0;
    public int name;

    public BoundingBox(int name, double xcoordi, double ycoordi, double boxWidth, double boxHeight) {
        this.name = name;
        this.xcoordi = xcoordi;
        this.ycoordi = ycoordi;
        this.boxWidth = boxWidth;
        this.boxHeight = boxHeight;
    }

    public int getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(int name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getXcoordi() {
        return xcoordi;
    }

    public void setXcoordi(double xcoordi) {
        this.xcoordi = xcoordi;
    }

    public double getYcoordi() {
        return ycoordi;
    }

    public void setYcoordi(double ycoordi) {
        this.ycoordi = ycoordi;
    }

    public double getWidth() {
        return boxWidth;
    }

    public void setWidth(double endX, double xcoordi) {
        boxWidth = endX - xcoordi;
    }

    public double getHeight() {
        return boxHeight;
    }

    public void setHeight(double endY, double ycoordi) {
        boxHeight = endY - ycoordi;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" +
                "Box=" + name +
                ", X=" + xcoordi +
                ", Y=" + ycoordi +
                ", Width=" + boxWidth +
                ", Height=" + boxHeight +
                '}';
    }
}
```

MousePosition.java:

```
package com.vaadin.starter.beveragebuddy.ui.components;

public class MousePosition {

    public double mouseX;
    public double mouseY;

    public MousePosition(double mouseX, double mouseY) {
        this.mouseX = mouseX;
        this.mouseY = mouseY;
    }

    public double getMouseX() {
        return mouseX;
    }

    public void setMouseX(double mouseX) {
        this.mouseX = mouseX;
    }

    public double getMouseY() {
        return mouseY;
    }

    public void setMouseY(double mouseY) {
        this.mouseY = mouseY;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MousePosition{" +
                "mouseX=" + mouseX +
                ", mouseY=" + mouseY +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Can you include the missing code from those two classes? It's a bit difficult to read and hides important information.

Comment: @Tazavoo Hello, I have updated and added all my code including the other classes in case there are any errors. Only MainLayout, Canvas and MousePosition contains the affected codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, with the updated code it seems your problem is that you never update the label.

You set the label text initially, but it will not be automatically updated when the array changes. What you can do is allow adding a listener to the canvas, and notify it when the value changes.

In the simplest case, a listener can be just a Java `Runnable` (or `Supplier` if you want to pass a value). My example returns a Vaadin `Registration`, which can be used to remove the listener by calling `registration.remove()`.

In `Canvas.java`

```
private List<Runnable> mouseMoveListeners = new ArrayList<>(0);

...

public Registration addMouseMoveListener(Runnable listener) {
    mouseMoveListeners.add(listener);
    return () -> mouseMoveListeners.remove(listener);
}
```

And in your current `mousemove` listener

```
// Your current code in the mousemove listener
MousePosition currentPos = new MousePosition(mouseX, mouseY);
mousePosArray.add(0, currentPos);
setMousePosArray(mousePosArray);
System.out.println(mousePosArray.get(0));

// Add this to run all the listeners that have been added to the canvas
mouseMoveListeners.forEach(Runnable::run);
```

Then at the end of your `MainLayout` constructor, something like this

```
 canvas.addMouseMoveListener(() -> label.setValue("Coordinates: " + mousePosArray));
```

This is untested code, but an approach similar to this should work. The point being that you somehow must notify the MainLayout when the array has changed.

Comment: You could also pass the `MainLayout` to the `Canvas` directly, and make the canvas call a method on the main layout to update it. However, this is not a great solution as the classes become very tightly coupled (both classes depend on each other).